# Basic highlightjs document won't work

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Highlightjs has very simple [usage](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) instructions, which I can't seem to get to work in the document below. I would expect the html within the `<pre> and <code>` to be displayed, but all I see is the text. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>  

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/styles/default.min.css">
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/highlight.min.js"></script>
 <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>

<body>
 
<pre>
 <code class="html">
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p>This should be escaped, highlighted html. </p>
   </body>
   </html>
 </code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is highlightjs does not escape code for you as was suggested to me. Good link [here](http://qnimate.com/displaying-and-highlighting-source-code-in-html-page/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/styles/default.min.css">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.5/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</head>

<body>
  
<pre>
  <code class="html">
     &#x3C;!DOCTYPE html&#x3E;
     &#x3C;html lang=&#x22;en&#x22;&#x3E;
     &#x3C;head&#x3E;
       &#x3C;meta charset=&#x22;UTF-8&#x22;&#x3E;
       &#x3C;title&#x3E;Document&#x3C;/title&#x3E;
     &#x3C;/head&#x3E;
     &#x3C;body&#x3E;
      &#x3C;p&#x3E;This should is highlighted html. &#x3C;/p&#x3E;
     &#x3C;/body&#x3E;
     &#x3C;/html&#x3E;
  </code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```